# Configure git to squash commits, not pulls

Tags: git

Is it possible to configure git to squash merges, but not squash changes from pulls? If it's possible, how would I configure git this way?

I configured git via `git config branch.<name>.mergeoptions --squash`

While that works for squashing the commits from merged branches, it also tries to squash incoming changes when doing a pull.

Comment: Without given a real answer, just: A `pull` is just a `fetch` and a `merge`. Thats the reason, why it's affected by the `mergeoptions` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ~/.gitconfig or .git/config per project basis.

```
...
[alias]
    ms = merge --squash
```

Edit: Overriding built-in commands are not possible, as per the git-config manpage. Updated answer to suggest having a separate command for just this.

> Command aliases for the git(1) command wrapper - e.g. after defining
>   "alias.last = cat-file commit HEAD", the invocation "git last" is
>   equivalent to "git cat-file commit HEAD". To avoid confusion and
>   troubles with script usage, aliases that hide existing git commands
>   are ignored. Arguments are split by spaces, the usual shell quoting
>   and escaping is supported. quote pair and a backslash can be used to
>   quote them.

Comment: How does it help? He asked to squash explicit merges but do not squash merges within pull.

Comment: AFAIK, the alias should not be applied within the merge stage of a pull, just when you invoke 'git merge'. Isn't that an explicit merge?

Comment: Yep, in git-pull.sh git-merge invoked explicitly i.e. bypassing any aliases. You are right.

Comment: This won't work anyway.  Git does not allow overriding builtin commands with an alias.

Comment: You are correct, I remembered doing something like this but it was obviously wrong. Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd need to do a `git fetch` and then a `git merge --no-squash` to do what you're wanting.  Or, if you want to do it in a single command, a simple git alias (or bash alias or function, for that matter) should suffice:

> git config alias.pull-no-squash '!git fetch; git merge --no-squash'